# Can jQuery Event which value be changed?

Tags: jquery

I would like to change the default behavior on my  elements:

```
$('form input').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) { // ENTER key
    e.setTempDefault(9); // TAB key
    // e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Obviously, `setTempDefault` does not exist.

All I can find is `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: So, basically, when someone presses enter, you want to go to the next field as if the user pressed tab.

Comment: Yes! I can catch and eat the keystroke, but the people using our forms are ultimately trying to go to the next field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('form input').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();  
        $(':input').eq( $(this).index(':input') + 1 ).focus();
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3cFJz/)